# Char conversion to date fails depending on where clause

Tags: sql-server, date, date-conversion

I am trying to set up a simple query on my data converting char YYYYMMDD to date type. I am using simple convert(date, MyDateColumn).

```
Select isdate(MyDateColumn),
       convert(date,MyDateColumn)
       FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTimeColumn = '000000'

Result: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Select isdate(MyDateColumn),
       MyDateColumn
       FROM MyTable
WHERE  MyTimeColumn = '000000'

Result:  1   20190821  

Select isdate(MyDateColumn),
       convert(date,MyDateColumn)
       FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateColumn = '20190821' AND MyTimeColumn = '000000'

Result:  1   2019-08-21
```

I have observed that this query has failed for me for specific row above depending whether I added where clause to MyDateColumn. I have added where clause MyDateColumn=MyDateColumn as a workaround. Any idea for a better solution?

I am using SQL Server 2016 (13.0.5201.2). MyDateColumn is char(10) type

Comment: What date is `'000000'` meant to represent? YOu say you have a column called `MyDateColumn`, but if it's *already* a `date`, why are you converting it to a `date`?

Comment: MyDateColumn is a char(10) column. And MyTimeColumn '000000' is really not relevant for the case. I am just pointing out another filter that might be affecting my results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is to stop storing your dates as text, in text columns, and to start using actual date columns instead.  The conversion failure in your very first query is alarming, and would seem to indicate that either you have non dates stored, or maybe there is some trailing/leading whitespace.  Since you are using SQL Server 2016, you may try the following query to flush out any non conforming date strings:

```
SELECT MyDateColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, MyDateColumn) IS NULL;
```

Once you have located the problematical records, you may fix them, and then give your queries another try.

Comment: Storing dates as text is a legacy coming from ERP system integration. Sometimes I get weird non-date text values in dates columns coming from ERP. Query above is a part of ETL cleansing the data.

But actually your idea got me to the point that TRY_CONVERT works correctly. I only had issue that I have set up compatibility level to SQL 2008 and thus TRY_CONVERT was not recognized function.

Comment: Great, if the query I gave you gives you an empty set, then it means your dates are all parsable.  Note that it's also possible that you could more than one date format, with which `TRY_CONVERT` might be better able to cope than regular `CONVERT`.